# Hierarchical viewmodels which represent UI structure. What is better approach?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

Sorry for long and descriptive question, but it really bugs me for a long time. I have a problem with MVVM pattern.

I wrote application which actually works, but I don't think it's in a good style. My view model strucure looks like tree: it has references to all child viewmodels which are used to render proper view in ContentPresenter.

Take a look at sample GUI:

Home tab

```
--------------------------------------
HOME    SETTINGS    ADMINPANEL
======---------------------------------
______________________________________
/////////
///////// Home content
/////////
```

Settings tab

```
--------------------------------------
HOME    SETTINGS    ADMINPANEL
------============---------------------
______________________________________
settings1 > settings2 > other...

/////////
///////// Settings1 content
/////////
```

Notice the submenu which appears only in Settings view. Every switchable view is somehow dependent on model type. settings1 is visible only if model property is Type.One, and settings2 is visible when property is Type.Two.

Take a fast look into my current code: common interface for every view that I can change by click. PageHeader is displayed on button change content view:

```
public interface IPageVM
{
    string PageHeader { get; set; }
}
```

and view models:

```
public class WindowVM : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<IPageVM> ViewModels { get; set; }
    public IPageVM CurrentTab { get; set; }
    public ICommand ChangeViewModel { get; set; }

    private Model _model;

    public WindowVM()
    {
        _model = new Model();

        ViewModels = new ObservableCollection<IPageVM>();
        ViewModels.Add(new HomeVM(model));
        ViewModels.Add(new SettingsVM(model));

        if(_model.Admin)
            ViewModels.Add(new AdminVM(model));
    }
}

public class HomeVM : ViewModelBase, IPageVM
{
    public string PageHeader { get { return "HOME"; } }
    string Property { get; set; }

    public HomeVM(Model model)
    {
        this.Property = model.Property;
    }
}

public class SettingsVM : ViewModelBase, IPageVM
{
    public string PageHeader { get { return "SETTINGS"; } }

    public ObservableCollection<IPageVM> Tabs { get; set; }
    public IPageVM CurrentTab { get; set; }
    public ICommand ChangeViewModel { get; set; }

    public SettingsVM(Model model)
    {
        Tabs = new ObservableCollection<IPageVM>();

        if(model.Type = Type.One)
            Tabs.Add(new Settings1VM(model));
        if(model.Type = Type.Two)
            Tabs.Add(new Settings2VM(model));

        Tabs.Add(new OtherSettingsVM());

        CurrentTab = Tabs[0];
    }
}

public class Settings1VM: ViewModelBase, IPageVM
{
    public string PageHeader { get { return "settings1"; } }

    public Settings1VM(Model model)
    {
    }
}

public class Settings2VM: ViewModelBase, IPageVM
{
    public string PageHeader { get { return "settings2"; } }

    public Settings1VM(Model model)
    {
    }
}
```

xaml:
display buttons in ItemsControl that will change CurrentViewModel and render appropriate view bounded to viewmodels' type by DataTemplate.

Pros:

- it already works
- I can easily tell how does my GUI structure looks, because root viewmodel contains its children viewmodels and so on.
- it's easy to inject data model to children by constructor.

Cons:

- xaml code is all a DataTemplate
- UserControls are empty in preview mode, it's hard to edit GUI
- terrifying future: how will look my viewmodels structure if my application will grow a bit?

So I decided to change my ViewModels to something that looks more like WPF MVVM:

```
public class WindowVM : ViewModelBase
{
    public bool AdminMode { get; set; }

    public WindowVM()
    {
        _model = new Model();
        AdminMode = _model.Admin;
        AnotherTabVisibilityDependency = _model.Dependency;
    }
}
```

xaml:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="HOME">
        <TabItem.DataContext>
            <vm:HomeVM/>
        </TabItem.DataContext>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="SETTINGS">
        <TabItem.DataContext>
            <vm:SettingsVM/>
        </TabItem.DataContext>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="ADMINPANEL" Visibility="{Binding AdminMode, Converter BoolToVisibility}">
        <TabItem.DataContext>
            <vm:AdminVM/>
        </TabItem.DataContext>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="DEPENDANT" Visibility="{Binding AnotherTabVisibilityDependency, Converter BoolToVisibility}">
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

As you probably see, everything is clean, chaning UI is easy; not too much templates to write. Everything looks fine... But there is a thing I don't understand: Now each ViewModel is a separate instance that doesn't know about its parent. I can't pass model that easy.

Questions:

- how can I inject data model into each viewmodel? I can't do it via xaml. Do I need to have a global static class with program state, or IoC? Maybe another way?
- any alternative approaches? Maybe my second approach also isn't good?
- does it make sense to rewrite my logic which actually works? I really hope it does (I hate my viewmodels' code).

Comment: What you're proposing is using your presentation for the structure of the application, and hanging bits of data off it, rather than the reverse. That strikes me as odd: Data/business logic should drive everything IMHO. Your objections to the old design don't resonate with me; you can use mock data at design time if you actually find the designer useful. I don't know why you don't like DataTemplates, and no design is future proof. But I'd rather face the future with your first design than your second (full disclosure: At work, that's exactly how I face the future).

Comment: "settings1 is visible only if model property is Type.One, and settings2 is visible when property is Type.Two": That's something you can design around with the architecture you've got, if it's a problem. Another important point, btw: Grand clean sheet redesigns are often disasters, unless the original design was a horrible accretive kludge that grew by accident and simply can't be sustained any more.

Comment: I got your point, and I could use mock data for preview. However I think what I have already done is not MVVM at all; I could use as well child controls in code-behind classes instead of child viewmodel..?

Comment: Depends on specifics; i use a lot of child VMs.

Comment: But what if I wanted to move sub-menu navigation (settings1 > settings2 > other...) **outside** the main presenter? for example if I wanted to change view to look like [this image](http://lh4.ggpht.com/-FxVz8U71Z9c/UZ50axpGQGI/AAAAAAAAEI4/fwpNyUtDwR0/image_thumb%25255B8%25255D.png)

Comment: Now viewmodels hierarchy will have to be changed as well as menu view, which will be very complicated (hierarchial data template?). This is bothering me a lot.

Comment: Again, that's something you can design around. The main viewmodel can expose a lot of commands and so on, either in a conventional way or by a "services" type of deal. A view populating a context menu can get a list of titled commands from the viewmodel, and the viewmodel's parent vm can have populated half that list without the viewmodel needing to know what's in there.

Comment: I don't know if that precisely answers that concern, but you get the general drift.